# We have a case where there are multiple projects configured in sonar. All the project have different modules with same names?

Tags: sonarqube

We have a case where there are multiple projects configured in sonar. All the project have different modules with same names.

With this, as and when we execute sonar for one of the project, the execution is getting terminated with below error.

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) on project XXX: Module "XXXX" is already part of project "YYYY" -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) on project XXXX: Module "YYYY" is already part of project "YYYY"

It seems that because the module name is same , Sonar is terminating the execution. Note that we are using sonar version 4.5.5 and facing this issue. While earlier we were using sonar version 4.1.1 and with that version the execution was successful (probably sonar was overriding earlier report with the newer one in case of conflicting module name).

Please suggest possible solution for this? Thanks,

Complete error log is available here

https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/sonarqube/-L7cby77-28/6L6zPlb6AAAJ

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to rename you modules like if your project is abc.
Please change your modules like abc_xxx etc...it may work for you

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the project name property?

In a pom.xml file:

```
<sonar.projectName>Some project name here</sonar.projectName>
```